# rails 3, how use an ENV config vars in a Settings.yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, env

In my settings.yml file I have several config vars, some of which reference ENV[] variables.

for example I have ENV['FOOVAR'] equals WIDGET

I thought I could reference ENV vars inside <% %> like this:

Settings.yml:

```
default:
   cv1: Foo
   cv2: <% ENV['FOOVAR'] %>
```

in rails console if I type

```
> ENV['FOOVAR']
=> WIDGET
```

but

```
> Settings.cv1
=> Foo   (works okay)
> Settings.cv2
=>nil   (doesn't work???)
```

Comment: You might want to checkout this guide about configuration, and local variables :
http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html
tl;dnr: figaro gem can be useful for that.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

use following:-

```
 default:
       cv1: Foo
       cv2: <%= ENV['FOOVAR'] %>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you dont add the .yml as .yml.erb file and add the code `template = ERB.new File.new("path/to/config.yml.erb").read
processed = YAML.load template.result(binding)'

Comment: @Faz also works if loading the file from app/config via `Rails.application.config_for()`

Answer (score 31):

The above solution did not work for me. However, I found the solution on 
[How do I use variables in a YAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722949/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-yaml-file)

My .yml file contained something like:

```
development:
gmail_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
gmail_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
```

The solution looks like:

```
template = ERB.new File.new("path/to/config.yml.erb").read
processed = YAML.load template.result(binding)
```

So when you introduce a scriptlet tag in .yml file, it is more of erb template. So read it as a erb template first and then load the yml as shown above.

Comment: The config file does not need to be with the `.erb` extention, it would also works on it if it was called `config.yml `

Answer (score 24):

Use `<%= ENV['FOOVAR'] %>` instead of `<% ENV['FOOVAR'] %>`.

Be aware that this approach will only work if whatever is parsing the Yaml file is set up to process it via Erb (for example, you can see [how Mongoid does exactly this](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/994f1aecfd56d5810c5af840c8698d055b4a7cb5/lib/mongoid/config.rb#L129)). It's not universally supported in Yaml files though, so it depends on what you're using this Yaml file for.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this with simple code

```
data = {}
YAML.load_file("path_of_file/settings.yml").each do |key, value|
  data[key] = ENV[value] || value
end
```

where my data was something like this

```
account: ACCOUNT_USERNAME
password: ACCOUNT_PASSWORD
port: 5002
```

and `ACCOUNT_USERNAME` and `ACCOUNT_PASSWORD` are environment variables

Comment: It is not a reliable solution. It may lead to some unexpected and hard-to-catch behavior when any value in the .yml file accidentally matches one of the environment variables. And you never know in which environment the application will run in the future. It's better to explicitly specify places where ENV variables are expected and use ERB parser.