# How do I use variables in a YAML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have YAML file which needs to take a variable as an input:

```
outputters:
    - type        : DateFileOutputter
      name        : logfile
      level       : DEBUG
      date_pattern: '%Y%m%d'
      trunc       : 'false'
      dirname     : "/home/sameera/workspace/project/log"
      filename    : "message.log"
      formatter   :
        date_pattern: '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
        pattern     : '%d %l - %m'
        type        : PatternFormatter
```

I want to pass `dirname` as a parameter, something like:

```
      dirname     : "<%= LOGFILE_PATH%>"
```

My `LOGFILE_PATH` is defined in a file called `init.rb`.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use ERB.

For example:

```
template = ERB.new File.new("path/to/config.yml.erb").read
processed = YAML.load template.result(binding)
```

You can read more on binding here: [ruby metaprogramming](http://reference.jumpingmonkey.org/programming_languages/ruby/ruby-metaprogramming.html#h4).

Comment: Hi @Sergio Tulentsev, It it worked, But since I wanted a pure yml solution, I tried to do the same with .yml but had no luck, thanks for  the answer and sorry for the delay of not posting any update cheers sameera

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev have you fixed this problem in any other way?(i.e based on yml)

Comment: @ManivannanJeganathan: I didn't try :)