# Rails does not properly read environmental variables in database.yml

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, environment-variables, passenger

My database.yml is set up as such:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: devel
  username: root
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  timeout: 5000

# ... snip ...

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: prod
  username: <%= ENV["DB_USER"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["DB_PASSWORD"] %>
  host: <%= ENV["DB_HOST"] %>
  port: 3306
  timeout: 5000
```

The issue is, though, despite setting my environmental variables, Rails is not reading these properly. When I start up my Phusion-backed Nginx server on EC2, I get this message:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)
```

I confirmed that Phusion is starting Rails in the production environment; I changed the usernames and hosts in the development and test configuration to unique names, and `'root'@'localhost'` always showed up as the error message. In addition, if I hard-code the username and password into the YAML file, the server starts up properly.

I suspect that I'm not setting my environmental variables correctly because MySQL keeps claiming that I'm trying to log in as 'root' without a password. I initially had them exported from the .bashrc file, but after reading [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/261802/profile-vs-bash-profile-vs-bashrc), I realized that this was not the proper way to do it. After searching around, I happened upon [this blog post](https://coderwall.com/p/djrfra), so I followed the instructions and created these three files:

/usr/local/etc/env

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
export DB_PASSWORD= (snip)
export DB_USER=doorbells
```

/usr/local/etc/ruby_wrapper

```
#!/bin/sh

source /usr/local/etc/env
exec /home/rooby/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p362@doorbells-dev/ruby "$@"
```

/etc/profile.d/env.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

source /usr/local/etc/env
```

In my nginx.conf file, I use this line:

```
passenger_ruby /usr/local/etc/ruby_wrapper;
```

I've rebooted my server to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: just a guess but you need to use database.yml.erb

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately. The file needs to be named 'database.yml'.

Comment: @gorelative it possible to interpolate variables in YAML files

Comment: This should work, or at least it does with Foreman and Webbrick, locally.

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same problem on Ubuntu 12.04.

In the nginx error log (`/var/log/nginx/error.log/`) I've seen, that

```
[ ... ]: [App 8509 stderr] /path/to/ruby_wrapper.sh: 2: /path/to/ruby_wrapper.sh: 
[ ... ]: [App 8509 stdout] 
[ ... ]: [App 8509 stderr] source: not found
```

`/bin/sh` seems to don't understand the `source` command. Thus, I've changed it to a simple `.`, which does the same.

The complete changed `ruby_wrapper.sh` would look like:

```
#!/bin/sh

. /usr/local/etc/env
exec /home/rooby/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p362@doorbells-dev/ruby "$@"
```

Does this help for you?

Comment: Hmm, I do recall deploying my Rails app onto an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I don't really do Rails anymore, but I'll try out your solution for closure. Surprised people are still digging this question up. :)

Answer (score 2):

The above solution did not work for me. However, I found the solution on 
[How do I use variables in a YAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722949/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-yaml-file)

My .yml file contained something like:

```
development:
gmail_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
gmail_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
```

The solution looks like:

```
template = ERB.new File.new("path/to/config.yml.erb").read
processed = YAML.load template.result(binding)
```

So when you introduce a scriptlet tag in .yml file, it is more of erb template. So read it as a erb template first and then load the yml as shown above.

Answer (score -5):

first, use

```
username: ENV["DB_USER"]
password: ENV["DB_PASSWORD"]
host: ENV["DB_HOST"]
```

instead

```
username: <%= ENV["DB_USER"] %>
password: <%= ENV["DB_PASSWORD"] %>
host: <%= ENV["DB_HOST"] %>
```

Comment: That is not correct. database.yml is evaluated as an ERB template so he definitely *should* use the `<%= %>` syntax.

Comment: @Hongli Unless you're using HAML, in which case you'll need to use string interpolation.

Comment: That is not true either. database.yml is *always* evaluated as an ERB template. It does not matter whether you use HAML for views or not.