# Mysql2::Error "Access denied for user" using env variable in database.yml

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My System is macOX Mojave 10.14 
MySQL is MySQL:8.0.16
My `database.yml` is:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: dev_database
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['RAILS_DEV_DB_USSERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RAILS_DEV_DB_PASSWORD'] %>
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

and I have confirmed if the variable is valid. Using

> Command-Line: erb config/database.yml

I can get:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: dev_database
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: Wle3S#23sv
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

But when I start `rails s -e developent`, and browse to my page, I can not connect to my database.

[image]

What can I do now?

Comment: what is the result of `echo $RAILS_DEV_DB_USSERNAME` in the terminal(non rails

Comment: `echo $RAILS_DEV_DB_USSERNAME` return `root` ,`echo $RAILS_DEV_DB_PASSWORD ` return my correct password.i checked

Comment: does changing the username to root work. In the database.yml file

Comment: you mean change `<%= ENV['RAILS_DEV_DB_USSERNAME'] %>` to `root`  in the database.yml?  still not working

Comment: Try doing `spring stop`

Comment: Did you just misspell `USERNAME` note you have 2 `S`s

Comment: `spring stop` return `Spring is not running`,I can't find out the reason,I just created a new rails project,and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Author arpiagar suggested [rails 3, how use an ENV config vars in a Settings.yml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866015/rails-3-how-use-an-env-config-vars-in-a-settings-yml-file) check his example (26)

> when you introduce a scriptlet tag in .yml file, it is more of erb template. So read it as a erb template first and then load the yml

You can use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) or [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gems (inspired by the Twelve-Factor App methodology) to loads environment variables.

For example if you use dotenv gem

```
By default, load will look for a file called .env in the current working directory. Pass in multiple files and they will be loaded in order. The first value set for a variable will win.

require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load('file1.env', 'file2.env')
HOSTNAME = ENV['HOSTNAME']
```

More info please check below mentioned links

1. http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html
2. https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-guide-environment-variables/